# Animating object from speed data in python

Tags: python, animation

This is the deal now...I have a speed data in a .DAT file; For example lets say the file looks like this

```
0.111
1.11
2.22
3.33
4.555
1.111
2.22
10.11
```

What this data represents is the instantaneous speed in m/s of a certain object, these data intervals are in 10 mil-second difference that means that we get the speed of the object in every 10 mil-second interval. So I was wondering on how I will convert this to a motion on an empty in blender using python. Any help or ideas in the comment is also more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Integrate the velocity curve.**

*Please note: Am currently working on an addon that uses 3rd party addons `scipy` (to integrate here) and `matplotlib` to plot.*

Displacement is the integration of the velocity curve.

Instead of 10ms between points (would need frame rate of 100fps for a frame each) have spread the velocity across the scene frame range. `dt` is how many frames between points.

`Scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` is used to integrate the velocity list, setting initial displacement to zero.  This is basically the [sum of the area of each trapezium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). Remember have bloated out the time scale, for strictly having  10ms between readings

```
t = np.linspace(0, len(v) * 10 / 1000, len(v))
s = integrate.cumtrapz(v, t, initial=0)
```

and the frame for 10ms (where fps = 24) can use the utility method.

```
>>> bpy.utils.time_to_frame(10 / 1000)
0.24
```

Result of `Matplotlib.pyplot`

[image]
*Displacement in blue, velocity (scaled by frames per point (`dt`)) in red*

The resulting fcurve.

[image]

Test script maps the displacement to the frame range, considering velocity as blend units per frame, rather than meters per second.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

plot = False


context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
ob.animation_data_create()
ad = ob.animation_data
action = ad.action or bpy.data.actions.new("Displacement")
ad.action = action

v = np.array(
    (
        0.111,
        1.11,
        2.22,
        3.33,
        4.555,
        1.111,
        2.22,
        10.11,
    )
)

t = np.linspace(
    scene.frame_start,
    scene.frame_end,
    len(v))
dt = t[1] - t[0]
s = integrate.cumtrapz(v, t, initial=0)
if plot:
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(t, s)
    plt.plot(t, dt * v)
    plt.savefig("disp.png")
    plt.show()
# ravelled list of frame, value keyframes
kfs = np.empty((v.size + t.size,), dtype=t.dtype)
kfs[0::2] = t
kfs[1::2] = s
# move in x location
fc = action.fcurves.find("location")
# remove if exists
if fc:
    action.fcurves.remove(fc)
fc = action.fcurves.new("location", index=0)
fc.keyframe_points.add(len(v))   
fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set("co", kfs)
# add linear velocity points before and after
kfs = np.insert(kfs, 0, (-dt, -v[0]))
kfs = np.append(kfs, (scene.frame_end + dt, s[-1] + v[-1]))
# set handles based on before / after
fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set("handle_left", kfs[:-2])
fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set("handle_right", kfs[2:])
```

Comment: Exemplary. Thank heavens I didn't have a shot at this one!