# Animating a wheel using a speed property only

Tags: rigging, drivers

I am trying to set up a wheel rig where the animator is provided with a single speed property only. The speed value should be keyed by the animator over time and the wheels should rotate accordingly.

Is there any way one could create such a rig? I tried different things using drivers, but drivers don't seem to work in a accumulative fashion.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116602/rotation-speed-setting  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167706/animating-object-from-speed-data-in-python  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80509/can-you-animate-objects-using-differential-equations  The car rigs of ROUBAL had a baking script to animate the wheels turning, or another option is a frame change handler